# Mongo findOne not returning data even if it exists with index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an answers schema with over 2M entries.
Schema is

```
{
  user: {                                                                                                                                     
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,                                                                                                        
      ref: 'User',                                                                                                                
  },                                                                                                                                  
  q: {                                                                                                                                        
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,                                                                                                        
      ref: 'Question',                                                                                                            
  },                                                                                                                                  
  answer: {                                                                                                                                   
      type: String,                                                                                                                       
      required: [true, 'Answer required'],                                                                                        
  } 
}
```

On the submitAnswers route, I'm checking with findOne based on user and q to see if an answer exists, if it exists then update else create

```
let check = await Answer.findOne({user: u_id, q: q_id})
if(check) {
    check.answer = new_answer
    await check.save()
    return res.json({message: "Answer saved"})
} else {
    let result = //Aggregate query
    if(result) {
         throw Error();
    }
    await Answer.create({user: u_id, q:q_id, answer: new_answer})
    return res.json({message: "Answer saved"})
}
```

I currently have the `{q: 1, user: 1}` index on the Schema for faster searches. Still, there are a lot of repeated data in the database with the same user and q values.

Can't use upsert as that would result in calling that aggregate query for check everytime and it's a heavy query

Am I missing something? OR the index creation takes time? It is a heavy user server.

**Facing this only on production server with concurrent users**

Answer (score 0):

What you likely have there is a race condition.  If 2 people submit the same u_id and q_id at that same time, both will find that there isn't one already, and skip down to the else block where they both create a new document.

Comment: Two people can't have same u_id and q_id because u_id is generated based on JWT and the system allows only single user login at a time.

Comment: Would still be possible unless you have somehow guarded against the user rapidly clicking/tapping submit

Comment: As the student clicks the submit button, the button gets disabled until the response comes from the server.

Comment: If you remove the duplicates and then create a unique index on {user:1, q:1}, you will enforce no duplicates while throwing an error if one is attempted, which should help find where it is happening.

Comment: I really don't wanna experiment with this on the prod backend. Else yeah it could really give me some more insights. Appreciate it :)